# Azure kubernetes and Azure API management : Azure AD authentication?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-aks

I have deployed both the frontend(AngularJS) and bacend(Asp.net core web api) on Azure kubernetes and I have Azure API management in front of the Azure kubernetes services.

As I can implement the Azure AD authentication either at the Azure kubernetes service or at the Azure API management level, which one I should choose to secure the application using Azure AD and why!?

Comment: AAD on kubernetes (unless you're doing something completely different from what I think you're doing) secures the control plane (kubectl), not your application.

Comment: Agree, however I could use MSAL with AngularJS to secure the application as well as asp.net core middle for securing the webaPI. My question is that should I use application level authentication or at APIM level? What are the pros and cons.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question. As it stands, it's very misleading. Authentication for AKS implies securing the control plane, not the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by deploying an AKS managed AD cluster. AKS-managed Azure AD integration is designed to simplify the Azure AD integration [experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/managed-aad)

Comment: Agree, I am not trying to secure the AKS cluster instead trying to setup authentication for the applications deployed.  I could use MSAL with AngularJS to secure the application as well as asp.net core middle for securing the webaPI. My question is that should I use application level authentication or at APIM level? What are the pros and cons.

Comment: You should definitely use application level authentication. Having APIM would give you another level of security. What if you need to deploy to another customer without APIM?

Comment: Does it mean that at APIM level I just have to valid claims and handle the authentication at application level?

Comment: go through this to understand https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/benefits-of-using-azure-api-management-with-microservices/